# How to spy two objects of same type in mockito

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

I have two Spy objects in my test class of similar types

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
class Test{

@InjectMocks
C c1;

@Spy
B b1=method1();

@Spy
B b2=method2();

@Test
public void myTest1()
{
 //Here I test functionality of c1
}

}
```

I want to test a method in C where b1 and b2 are used as spies.
I am not able to do this in my test class.
Both are getting initialized to null.If I remove one then one spy object based on alphabetical order gets initialized.

Comment: Don't you mind to use Mockito.spy static method?

Comment: That isn't solving my problem, spy(T object) I am not able to specify my method.

Comment: What do you mean by specify the method. Please, extend your question

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to specify your method"? The parameter is the object you want to lay a spy-proxy around. If your methods `method1()` and `method2()` return an instance of `B` which you want to Spy, then of course you can use the method. (`B b2 = Mockito.spy(method2());`) (even if I don't know if that solves your original problem)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!